# SQL code tin python that take input information

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have the following Python function which uses SQL-code and given a specific keyword to make some calculations. How can I redefine this function so that it asks the user for a keyword, i.e. the keyword doesn't have to be predefined in the SQL-code?

**The code looks as follow:**

```
def proto(cursor):
    cursor.execute('select protein.accession, keyword from protein JOIN protein_keywords ON protein.accession=protein_keywords.accession JOIN species ON protein.species_id=species.species_id where keyword="Zytocin";')
    return cursor.fetchall()
```

EDITED based on answer:

```
def zroto(cursor):
    cursor.execute('select latin AS ART, count(*) AS Antal from protein, species where species.species_id = protein.species_id group by species.species_id;')
    return cursor.fetchall()


def proto(cursor):
     sql = 'select protein.accession, keyword from protein JOIN protein_keywords 
     ON protein.accession=protein_keywords.accession JOIN species ON 
     protein.species_id=species.species_id where keyword = ?;'

     k=input('Enter the value of keyword')
     cursor.execute(sql,[k],)
     return cursor.fetchall()

def main(db_file):
    con, cur = get_connection(db_file)
    zroto_1 = zroto(cur)
    proto_1 = proto(cur)
    for row in zroto_1, proto_1:
        print(row)
```

Comment: I'm using sqlite3, and for python 3.7, I'm using Spyder on a Windows computer.

Comment: just replace `%s;` with `?` while using `cursor.execute(sql, ("Zytocin",))`

Comment: That, was nice, but I wanna manually input a word, e.g. "Zytocin", in console and then get the correct output. Not that I have to input this word already in the code. How can I do that?

Comment: For example, if I type proto("Zytocin" ) in console, I only get "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'execute'".

Comment: `k=input('Enter the value of keyword')`  and then `cur.execute(sql,[k],)`

Comment: Like I updated the code in the question above?

Comment: yes, what did you get? (don't forget to remove semi-colon at the endof the sql string)

Comment: The output looks ok, but the only problem is that I have another function before this function, that I wanna be exectued,before this function (see edited code above), but the program starts with asking for the keyword for the second function. How can I solve this?

Comment: What I mean is that the function called "zroto" should be runned first, then I should be asked for the keyword and then the "proto-function" should be runned. Not keyword -> zroto -> proto. Is that clear?

Comment: the question is evaluated to a completely different one :)

Comment: It think is just a matter of the structure of the code. i.e. which order.

Comment: What I mean is that I don't want the program to start by asking for the keyword, it should be done in the right order. Let's assume I have 1000 different functions and the "proto"-function is  function number 999, then I don't want the program to start by asking for which keyword in function 999. Right? The other 998 functions should be executed first, then asking for the keyword.

Comment: Put you need a "def main" function to exectue the program right? How can I order this so the question for keyword will be asked in the right order.?

Comment: At present, the program looks as follow: "Enter the value of keyword" --> function zroto executed --> function proto exectued. I want it like this: function zroto executed --> "Enter the value of keyword" --> function proto executed. Is that clear?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 2):

You would use a prepared statement:

```
sql = 'select protein.accession, keyword from protein JOIN protein_keywords ON protein.accession=protein_keywords.accession JOIN species ON protein.species_id=species.species_id where keyword = %s;'
cursor.execute(sql, ("Zytocin",))
return cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: Ok, but I want the user of the program to manually write the word. For exampel, if the user types "zyto", then nothing should happen, but if you write "Zytocin", the correct data should be printed.

Comment: What I mean is that you possibly should be able to type any word, but only for example "Zytocin", would give an output. In addition, when I typed your code I only got "OperationalError: near "%": syntax error".

Comment: See edited answer. Could I possibly use that code?